# Is it possible to redirect an index.php file back to its parent directory

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect an index.php file back to its parent directory and I am getting a redirect loop error.

Is it possible to redirect

http://www.example.com/contact/index.php

to

http://www.example.com/contact/

Comment: This to me doesn't look like a url redirect but more like a url rewrite. Might want to look into that. Otherwise yes you will get a redirect loop.

Comment: Yep this is a url rewrite

This did the trick

DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1/index.html [L]

Comment: You should put that as your answer. Then make the question as answered.